# Remove ibplugin from xib

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4, xib, ibplugin

How to remove all traces of ibplugins from .xib files?  My Xcode3 project had around 10 custom ibplugins used lots of places through out my around 20 .xib files. I have reworked this code so it no longer rely on ibplugins nor bindings so it now can compile in Xcode4.

However Xcode4 still complains that there are traces of the original ibplugins in my .xib files.

```
/* com.apple.ibtool.warnings */
/Users/johndoe/MyProject/English.lproj/MainWindow.xib: warning: ibtool encountered an error while loading the Interface Builder plug-in from /Users/johndoe/MyProject/Core/build/Debug/Core.ibplugin.
    Underlying Errors:
        Description: Can't load plugin, as there is no bundle at /Users/johndoe/MyProject/Core/build/Debug/Core.ibplugin.
```

I have removed the ibplugins from Interace Builder's preferences and re-saved all the .xib files. I have removed the target that build the .ibplugin. I have removed all the source files that was use for the .ibplugin. I have clean builded. My Xcode4 is installed on a completely different machine than my Xcode3 machine, so there is no way that there can be remains of ibplugins in its preferences. I have tried re-saving all the .xib files using Xcode4 too so all the .xib files now use Document Version: Default Version (Interface Builder 4.2).

One thing I haven't tried though is to re-create all the .xib files from scratch with Xcode4.

Any ideas how to remove all traces of .ibplugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

In Target Settings under "Interface Builder XIB Compiler - Options" I had "Plug-Ins" set to the path to my custom ibplugins. By setting "Plug-Ins" to an empty string all the warnings disappeared.